# Get a different value inside json as3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I have a code that gives me this JSON data:

```
{"122":[{"2":0,"1":0,"0":2692,"5":0},{"2":1,"1":0,"0":2689,"5":0}]}
```

When I trace `dataObject['122'][0]['0']`
It gives me the first one which is 2692.

How can I detect what the "2" is and after that judging by the "2" get the "0"?

Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to know, because you mix up the property names which happen to be numbers with phrases like "first" and second. Please clarify what exact value you want to retrieve. Btw, this looks like a really bad way to organise data.

Comment: I want to somehow check in which objects the "0" is equal something.

Comment: "*I want to somehow check in which objects the "0" is equal something.*" In your question, you ask about something entirely different: "*How can I detect what the "2" is*". Your question is still unclear. Also, where C do you get this data structure from? It's really horrible.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the "0" or the "2", all I need to check for example in which object something is equal something. lets say I want to know "2".

So I want to check somehow what objects include "2":1

Comment: Nope, doesn't make any sense. I give up trying to understand this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you get the most answer just you need to change to dataObject['122'][0]['2']

Comment: Yeah but I don't know which object's "0" is 2692

Comment: in your object "0":2692, it has the value